# .JSP and servlets connecting to .java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having trouble trying to run my program. It is supposed to get the information from the JSP page to the servlet, so that it can be passed through methods in a java class to be verified. Then, once verified the servlet determines whehter to send th emessage to the previous JSP page or to the success JSP page. When I run the program, it brings me to the RegisterUser.jsp page. I enter the information and then hit submit. It brongs me to a 404 not found page. The link says it is trying topoint me to the CreateUser.java servlet. It shouldn't be doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated whether it is just a link to where I can find information or some actual solution help. Thank you.

1. CreateUser.java SERVLET:

   ```
   @WebServlet(name = "createUser", urlPatterns = {"/createUser"})
    public class CreateUser extends HttpServlet {

   /**
    * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
    * methods.
    *
    * @param req
    * @param resp
    * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
    * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
    */

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)   throws ServletException, IOException {
       System.out.println("in process login.java");
       ServletContext context = getServletContext();

       // Extract password and id from login.jsp form

       String userName = req.getParameter("USERNAME");
       String password = req.getParameter("PASSWORD");
       String answerOne = req.getParameter("ANSWERONE");
       String answerTwo = req.getParameter("ANSWERTWO");
       String answerThree = req.getParameter("ANSWERTHREE");

       Boolean duplicateUser = User.verifyUserExists(userName);

       HttpSession session = req.getSession();
       if (duplicateUser) {
           req.setAttribute("MESSAGE", "UserName is in use. Try again");
           context.getRequestDispatcher("/RegisterUser.jsp").forward(req, resp);
       }
       else{
           User user = new User(userName, password, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree);
           user.addUser(user);
           req.getRequestDispatcher("RegistrationSuccessful.jsp").forward(req, resp);
       }

   }
   ```

   }
2. RegisterUser.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>

    <body>
        <H1>New User Registration</H1>
        <H3>Required Information</H3>

        <FORM name="CREATE" action="servlets/CreateUser.java" method="POST" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><INPUT name="USERNAME" maxlength="50" size="40" type="text" ></TD>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><INPUT name="PASSWORD" maxlength="50" size="40" type="password" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Favorite Vacation Spot:</td>
                    <td><INPUT name="ANSWERONE" maxlength="50" size="40" type="text" ></TD>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mother's Maiden Name:</td>
                    <td><INPUT name="ANSWERTWO" maxlength="50" size="40" type="text" ></TD>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Pet's Name:</td>
                    <td><INPUT name="ANSWERTHREE" maxlength="50" size="40" type="text" ></TD>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" onClick = "CreateUser.java"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </FORM>
        <p>${MESSAGE}</p>

    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

1. User.java class

public class User {

```
private String userName;
private String password;
    private String answerOne;
    private String answerTwo;
    private String answerThree;
    private static File file = new File("C:\\Users.txt");

    @SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")
    public User(String un, String pw, String a1, String a2, String a3) {
        setUserName(un);
        setPassword(pw);
        setAnswerOne(a1);
        setAnswerTwo(a2);
        setAnswerThree(a3);

    }

    public void addUser(User user) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(getFile());
        try (BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
            bfw.write(user.userName);
            bfw.write(user.password);
            bfw.write(user.answerOne);
            bfw.write(user.answerTwo);
            bfw.write(user.answerThree);
            bfw.newLine();
        }

    }

    public static boolean verifyUserExists(String userName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scannedFile = new Scanner(getFile());
        while (scannedFile.hasNext()) {
            String search = scannedFile.next();
            return search.equals(userName);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Boolean verifyPassword(String userName, String password) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scannedFile = new Scanner(getFile());
        while (scannedFile.hasNext()) {
            String search = scannedFile.next();
            if (search.equals(userName)) {
                return scannedFile.nextLine().equals(getMD5(password));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String getMD5(String input) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
            String hashtext = number.toString(16);
            // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
            }
            return hashtext;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Trying changing `action="servlets/CreateUser.java"`to `action="servlets/CreateUser"`

Comment: I just ran it with that suggestion, and still received the same error page. I've tried changing the paths and names to get it to at least stop trying to direct me to my servlet which can't be viewed in the browser.

Comment: Change action="servlets/CreateUser.java" to action="/createUser".

Comment: Still had the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 action="createUser" OR action="./createUser"
```

---

action="/createUser" will call the URL of default context

```
http://localhost:8084/createUser
```

while  action="./createUser"  will call the URL pattern of the servlet in the current directory/context

```
 http://localhost:8084/ContextName/createUser
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that it was in my logic of create user. I needed to make sure my file existed before I could do anything. It now works, and runs correctly. That's why it was giving me the 404 error. The file wasn't found.